# Detecting SQL Server reboot

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

My c# console app runs on an different machine than my SQL Server 2014. I use ado.net to connect to it. How can I detect if the sql server automatically reboots after installing windows updates? On my client application I use SystemEvents_SessionEnding but this does not help me.

I read about connection resiliency, but this seems also not to solve this problem.

Is there a specific ado.net event I can capture? Creating an app on the server sending UDP is not my prefered solution, aswell I dont want to use ping etc.

I'm really looking for something like an event to react on.

e.g. the notification services: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

Thanks!

Comment: which of the following you exactly want to detect?  is server _available_ or _restarted since your last interaction with it_ or _detect if the sql server automatically reboots after installing windows updates_

Comment: I want to know it is before restarting to pause my application and continue as soon it is available again.

Comment: Your problem doesn't sound particularly unique. That is, anybody that wants to have resiliency in their application will do something similar. One common approach is to try to connect (or use a pooled connection) and, if you get an error that suggests that the server is unavailable, you try again with successively longer intervals until you're successful. Search for "exponential backoff" for ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see if the server is down or not you can use [Ping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx) Class.

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

var ping = new Ping();
var reply = ping.Send("SqlServerIP");

if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
    //server is available
}
else
{
    //server is down
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not really help me. I dont want to ping on every ado.net exception i get to detect if the server is down. I want to pause my whole program for e.g. 3 Minutes when I get a notification the server will go away for a reboot.

Comment: IMHO, If you want to get a notification that the server will be down for a reboot, then it is server side code not client side.